# Cordova keyboard shrinkView with Chinese keyboard

Tags: cordova, shrink

I have met a problem with cordova keyboard plugin(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard):

Enable Shrink View by JS code Keyboard.shrinkView(true);

It's Ok when click input field and use English keyboard to type word, and it works when I set hideFormAccessoryBar to false in Chinese keyboard.

But when I set hideFormAccessoryBar to true, the Chinese keyboard works well on the first init in app, but when the keyboard open again, it will damaged WebView when I tapped any words, it will cause the status bar to black in iOS, and push the WebView down.

By the way I use Framework 7 message layout, and the keyboard problems only happen in this page.

Comment: Could you add some code example?

Comment: My page code is [this](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/messages.html#.Va_pja2qqko), and the keyboard problem only occurs in this page :